# How to fix phpmyadmin error 200?

Tags: phpmyadmin

PhpMyAdmin is giving randomly notification:

```
Error in Processing Request
Error code: 200
Error text: OK
```

Any idea how to fix ?

**Edit**:

i  restart  many  times  but  problem is the same  ?  anybody that can fix  this  ?

i remove  and reinstall  phpMyadmin  but  still no working  and  message  is same

Error al Procesar la Petición
Código de error: 200

S.O.S

Alvaro

Comment: Check your webserver error log and access log and see if there's anything relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting server helped me fix the problem.